# Runtime error with 2d Array "std::bad_alloc()" what()

Tags: c++, arrays

I have dynamically allocated a 2D array of size 1100*10^9 and I am getting the following runtime error -

[This is the runtime error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cista.png)

I don't encounter this error if I decrease the size of the array to 1100*10^5 .
Please Help . Thanks in advance .
Edit - I have added the part where I allocate the array.

```
 unsigned int** cache = new unsigned int*[1100] ;
for (int i = 0 ; i < 1100 ; i++)
    cache[i] = new unsigned int [1000000000] ;
```

Comment: That is a really large allocation. I assume you are not using a supercomputer or even a server with a few TB of virtual memory.

Comment: Well , I am using a cheap laptop with 8 Gb of RAM . I think I messed up real bad .

Comment: Have you considered subsampling your dataset or perhaps a sparse matrix would work.

Comment: At the moment I don't know much about sparse matrix and subsampling , but I would definitely read and try to implement them . Thanks for the help .

Comment: I think sparse matrix would not be helpful because most of the elements are going to be non-zero .

Answer (score 0):

`1100 * 10^9` is `1.1*10^12` elements. Let's for a moment assume that these elements are 4-byte integers, that's a total allocation of:

`4.4 * 10^12` bytes

dividing by 1024 * 1024 * 1024 to get gigabytes...

`1,048,017.748 GB` - which is about a thousand terabytes.

I don't think there is a processor architecture anywhere on the planet which can address, let alone allocate, this much ram.

(although if I'm wrong about this I'd be fascinated to hear it!)

Comment: I'm wondering how come my program was running for 1.1*10^8 elements of 8 byte integers without throwing an error with a RAM of 8 GB . I think I'm missing some logic .

Comment: @PSaiManideep can you post a minimal example of the code?